# Snapping to nearest street Directions service from a database of points

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

I have a MYSQL database of points that contain longitude, latitude, I'm reading the database and generating XML for the javascript Google API directions service to snap the points onto the nearest streets. This is from setting the origin and destination to itself.

PROBLEM:

Only one point is snapped to the street and the rest arent displayed at all, and also the map zooms into the point. I have a feeling this is because Directions Service is Asynchrous, but I am not sure how to correct this issue so it will snap all the points to the nearest street from the database.

The db code works and displays all the points if I don't try to use the Directions service and snap them to the street

Javascript Source Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>PHP GOOGLE MAPS POINTS</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[



var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function load() {

      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.06761, -79.9022),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


      // read in Long, lat from MYSQL DB from PHP file generated XML
      downloadUrl("phpmap.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

          var request = {
          origin:point,
          destination:point,
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });

           //






        }
      });


    }



    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

 <body onload="load()">
<div style="width: 600px; height: 600px;" id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the directionsRenderer will zoom the map to fit the displayed directions unless you set the preserveViewport option to true.
2. Why do you need all the points in your database snapped to the nearest road?  That is not what the directions service was intended for.  It is asynchronous and subject to a quota and a rate limit (check the value of "status", it should explain why you are only getting one result).  If you want points for each entry in your database that are snapped to the nearest road, capture them offline and save them in your database as well.

Comment: what do you mean capture them offline?

Comment: How are you getting the coordinates of your points in your database?  Generate these points at the same time would be one option.

Comment: Ah ok, getting them with a GPS module only when a certain event happens, so when that event happens snap it to a road, get the coordinates, store the processed coordinates to database then I can display all the points at once using normal methods